# How to redirect with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect

http://www.example.com/component/plant/?view=plant&plant-id=477
to
http://www.example.com/component/plant/?view=plant&id=477

I need to delete word plant from the url last.
I tried this but didnt get the proper result

```
RewriteEngine On
# Capture (\d+) into %1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} plant-id=(\d+) [NC]
# And rewrite (redirect) into id=%1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /component/plant/?view=plant&$1?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

But it's not work fine for me.

Comment: You have to post what you tried so far. Include your `.htaccess` style file in the question by using the `edit` button above.

Comment: Apart from that: always be more specific than just writing "does not work". No one can help you if you do not write the details. What _IS_ actually happening? Any entries in the _log files_? Anything else that might be of interest?

Comment: Hi, 

Just add what i done before, but it show url something like this

Comment: http://www.gardeningwithangus.com.au/component/plant/?view=plant&index.php%3fid=477

Where  index.php%3f this part is extra i dont need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(view=plant)&plant-id=([0-9]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(component/plant)/?$ /$1/?%1&id=%2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Did you try same URI `/component/plant/?view=plant&plant-id=477` ?

Comment: Make sure this is first rule in your `.htaccess` and there is NO other .htaccess in system.

Comment: When tried your link it became: `http://www.gardeningwithangus.com.au/component/plant/?view=plant&id=477` and that is CORRECT. Make sure you try in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Thanks Work Like A Charm ... !

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Please delete your duplicate questions.

Comment: One more thing i have a website page calender.php i need to redirect it to 
vcalendar/search.php?s_keyword=+&amp;s_category=&amp;s_event_date_from=[[todays date]] &amp;s_event_date_to=&amp;Button_DoSearch.x=21&amp;Button_DoSearch.y=9

Comment: @Daiyan: That definitely looks like a new question. Why don't you update this problem in one of the other questions so that I can provide a separate answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest .htaccess redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /component/plant/?view=plant&plant-id=477 /component/plant/?view=plant&id=477
```

or php-redirect:

```
<?php
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/component/plant/?view=plant&id=477' ) ;
?>
```

Comment: I add something more in body as well in above comments , please try to understand what i am looking for , Thanks

Comment: if the script address didn't change, why not to make conditional assignment `code` $var = ($_GET['plant-id'])?$_GET['plant-id']:$_GET['id'];

Comment: I need with .httacess